# Add attribute to xmltype with value taken from sequence

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltype

I am using Oracle XE in version 11.2.

I have such kind of XML:

```
<root>
    <x a="a"/>
    <x a="b"/>
    <x a="c"/>
</root>
```

No I would like to add attribute `b` to each element `x` with value taken from sequence, but it should take new value for each element. Expected result is:

```
<root>
    <x a="a" b="1"/>
    <x a="b" b="2"/>
    <x a="c" b="3"/>
</root>
```

I've found that to add attribute to XML I can use `insertchildxml` but in is adding the same (frist) value from sequence to all attributes `b`. I can't find how to call this function for each individual element `x`.

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finaly found some solution and key to it was to use XMLTable() function. Here is my code:

```
declare
v_inXML xmltype;
  v_tmpXML xmltype;
  v_withIdXML xmltype;
  v_outXML xmltype;
BEGIN   
  v_inXML := XMLType('<root><x a="a"/><x a="b"/><x a="c"/></root>');
  v_withIdXML := XMLType('<root/>'); 
  v_outXML := XMLType('<root/>');

  for c_rec in (
    select *
    from   XMLTable('for $i in /root/x
          return $i'
          passing  v_inXML
          columns x xmltype path '/x'
    )
  )
  loop
    select insertchildxml(c_rec.x,'//x', '@b', pckg_ent_pk_seq.nextval) into v_tmpXML from dual;      
    select insertchildxml(v_withIdXML, '/root', 'x', v_tmpXML) into v_withIdXML from dual;    
  end loop;

  select updatexml(v_outXML, '/root', v_withIdXML) into v_outXML from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_outXML.getClobVal());
END;
```

And the result is:

```
<root><x a="a" b="92"/><x a="b" b="93"/><x a="c" b="94"/></root>
```

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by various ways. Choice depends on how source data constructed, desired output format etc.

**1. XSLT Transformation**

Use [`XMLTransform()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions229.htm) function to add attribute.

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17239)

```
  with params as (
    select 
      XMLParse( content
        '
        <root>
            <x a="a"/>
            <x a="b"/>
            <x a="c"/>
        </root>                  
        '
      ) as doc_field
    from dual
  )
  select
    XMLTransform( 
      doc_field,
      XMLParse( content
        ' 
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">    
           <root>
           <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
             <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates> 
           </xsl:for-each>
           </root>
        </xsl:template>
          <xsl:template match="x">
              <x  a="{@a}" b="{position()}" />
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
        '
      )
    )
  from params
```

**2. XQuery returning single XML**

Using [`XMLQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions224.htm) function single XML can be translated to another, basically same variant as above.

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17238)

```
with params as (
  select 
    XMLParse( content
      '
      <root>
          <x a="a"/>
          <x a="b"/>
          <x a="c"/>
      </root>                  
      '
    ) as doc_field
  from dual
)
select
  XMLQuery( 
    '
      <root>
      {
        for $x at $pos in $doc/root/x
        return <x a="{$x/@a}" b="{$pos}" />
      }
      </root>
    '
    passing doc_field as "doc"
    returning content
  )
from params
```

**3. Get values from order of rows**

This method better matches cases when XML must be constructed on the fly and sequence attribute value can be injected at construction phase.

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17241)

```
with params as (
  select 'a' a from dual union all
  select 'b' a from dual union all
  select 'c' a from dual 
)
select
  XMLElement("root",
    XMLAgg(
      XMLElement("x",
        XMLAttributes(
          a as "a",
          rownum as "b"
        )  
      )
    )
  )
from params
```

Last method also can help with already built XML if you break it to records with [`XMLTable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) function.

Comment: Probably I was not clear enough in my question. When I was writing "value taken from sequence" I meant from Oracle Sequence Object. So the first two solutions are not working for me. I've finaly found some solution and key to it was, as you also said, `XMLTable()` function. I've created a cursor basic on `XMLTable` and then for each row I modified my XML using `insertchildxml`. After it I've created new `root` element with updated rows and I've updated existing one using `updatexml` (in the question there is only example, real case was more complicated).

Comment: @kpater87 Ok. So you can write your own answer and accept it.