# Need to update one attribute in oracle register xml schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, xsd

I have one only attribute difference in the latest schema compared with the previous version. So, I want to update that attribute alone instead of dropping the previous version and reregistering the new version. please let me know if more details are required. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can remember you cant, you have to drop and register it again

Comment: Thanks @OracleDev.                                                     I need to add new attribute instead of updating the existing one. Similar to the scenario which is present in the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773488/add-attribute-to-xmltype-with-value-taken-from-sequence

Comment: @OracleDev yes only way is to drop and reregister again. I am trying to delete the dependent xsd file using dbms_xmlschema.DELETE_CASCADE_FORCE but it is not deleting  and not showing any warnings/errors. Could someone help in this case ?

Comment: hm,thats weird. Is the registered schema seen if you execute "select * from user_xml_schemas "? It should delete if you use dbms_xmlschema.deleteSchema('yourschema.xsd',dbms_xmlschema.DELETE_CASCADE); or at least show the error if not.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OracleDev. I deleted using above approach.

Comment: @OracleDev When I try to see the data in Table "A". I am getting error like "ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete" after deregistering and registering the "C.xsd" file. Could you please provide your inputs ? Note: The Table "A" is dependent on "B.xsd" and "B.xsd" is dependent on "C.xsd".